# Dense subset of space of measures respecting a stronger norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $M(\mathbb R)$ the space of complex Borel measures with the norm $\Vert \mu \Vert = \vert \mu \vert(\mathbb R)$, where $\vert \mu \vert$ is the total variation of $\mu$. Now consider for $\alpha \geq 0$ the norm 
$$ \Vert \mu \Vert_{\alpha} := \int_{\mathbb R} e^{\alpha \vert s \vert} \, \vert \mu \vert (ds)$$
on the space $M_\alpha(\mathbb R):= \{\mu \in M(\mathbb R): \Vert \mu \Vert_{\alpha} < \infty\}$. I want to show that the set of measures with compact support $M_c(\mathbb R)$ are dense in $M_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ (which is a Banach algebra).

I have no concrete idea to how to get this. I know that $M_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $M(\mathbb R)$ and that $\Vert \mu \Vert \leq \Vert \mu \Vert_{\alpha}$ for all $\mu \in M_\alpha(\mathbb R)$. But I don't see how to get the result from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\mu\in M_\alpha$ you can construct a sequence of measures with compact support converging to $\mu$ in sort of the most obvious way imaginable: Let $d\mu_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}d\mu$. In other words, define $$\mu_n(E)=\mu(E\cap[-n,n]).$$

Comment: I know this sequence converges to $\mu$ in $\Vert \cdot \Vert$. But how do I show that this sequence converges to $\mu$ in $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\alpha$? That is the crucial point of my question.

Comment: $||\mu-\mu_n||_\alpha=\int_{|s|>n}e^{\alpha|s|}\,d|\mu|\to0$ by dominated convergence.